# I need to do a site redirects to a page after 21.45 to 10.00

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I need to do a site redirects to a page after 21.45 to 10.00
I need a script that would do a redirect site to another page at a certain time.

Here's what happened.

```
<?php
 $date = new DateTime('now');
         $date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'));
     if ($date->format('H')>=10 && $date->format('H')<=21  ){
        if ($date->format('H')==21 && $date->format('i')<45)    
          echo "<script>window.location = '/'</script>";                  
        else if($date->format('H')<21)
          echo "<script>window.location = '/'</script>";
     } 
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure with timezone, but

```
$hoursMinutes = intval(date("Hi"));
if($hoursMinutes >= 1000 && $hoursMinutes <=2145) {
    header("Location: /2");
} else {
    header("Location: /1");
}
```